# OLE DB Object field to SQL image field migration c#

Tags: sql, ms-access, object, migration, ole

I am trying to migrate OLE object field (access 2003) to SQL 2005 field, now I managed to get Doc file working (function copied),

but no luck with EXCEL/PDF and other files.

```
        short sFlag = 0;
        int nIndex = 0;
        int nCount = 0;
        int nOffset = 0;
        int nImgLen = 0;
        int nReadbyte = 14400;
        string szImgType = string.Empty;


        if (bData.Length > 0)
        {
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(bData, true);
            byte[] bArray = new byte[nReadbyte];
            nCount = memStream.Read(bArray, 0, nReadbyte);
            if (bArray[78] == (byte)0x42 && bArray[79] == (byte)0x4D) //BMP FORMAT
            {
                sFlag = 1;
                nOffset = 78;
                szImgType = "image/bmp";
            }
            else
            {
                for (nIndex = 78; nIndex < nReadbyte - 2; nIndex++)
                {
                    if (bArray[nIndex] == (byte)0xFF && bArray[nIndex + 1] == (byte)0xD8) //JPG FORMAT
                    {
                        sFlag = 2;
                        nOffset = nIndex;
                        szImgType = "image/pjpeg";
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (bArray[nIndex] == (byte)0x25 && bArray[nIndex + 1] == (byte)0x50) //PDF FORMAT
                    {
                        sFlag = 3;
                        nOffset = nIndex;
                        szImgType = "application/pdf";
                        FileType = "application/pdf";
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (bArray[nIndex] == (byte)0xD0 && bArray[nIndex + 1] == (byte)0xCF) //MSWORD FORMAT
                    {
                        sFlag = 4;
                        nOffset = nIndex;
                        szImgType = "application/msword";
                        FileType = "application/msword";
                        break;
                    }


                }
            }
            if (sFlag > 0)
            {
                nImgLen = bData.Length - nOffset;
                memStream.Position = 0;
                memStream.Write(bData, nOffset, nImgLen);
                memStream.Position = 0;
                byte[] bImgData = bData; //new byte[nImgLen];
                return bImgData;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }


        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

will like to know any pointers/ lookups to migrate ole objects to SQL 2005 fields.

-Prash

Comment: Why do you feel it's important to store the files in the database?

Comment: no, i know its bad idea, but i am stuck with it. The db and application is already in place, and migration is last step.

Comment: Ah! was not 100% successful but after few hours of search on net found  that we need to search for doctype and then convert the files based on it. still 2007 and few versions of PDFs are problem.